# Hilt (java) - Field Injection in Custom Class

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

So i'm trying to inject an object with the `@Inject` annotation in a class that is not related to:

```
Application (mediante @HiltAndroidApp)
Activity
Fragment
View
Service
BroadcastReceiver
```

But i can't do it. Maybe i'am doing something wrong because i can do the injection via constructor.

[image]

As you can see. The @Inject annotated object is null but the object received from the constructor is created.

Here is my code:

```
ApplicationModule

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent.class)
public class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    public Context providesApplicationContext(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return context;
    }

    @Provides
    public CompositeDisposable providesCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    ...
}

HomeViewModel

public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeViewModel";

    private CatalogInteractor catalogInteractor;
    @Inject
    public CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

    @Inject
    public HomeViewModel(CatalogInteractor catalogInteractor, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        this.catalogInteractor = catalogInteractor;
    }
    
    ...
}

HomeFragment

@AndroidEntryPoint
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    HomeViewModel        viewModel;
    LoginViewModel       loginViewModel;
    ViewModelProvider.Factory factory;

    @Inject
    HomeViewModelFactory homeViewModelFactory;
    @Inject
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable; // Injected here just to validate the correct creation

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                closeDrawer();
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);

    }

    ...

}
```

So i don't know if i'am doing something wrong or if it is a Hilt issue.

**TLDR**: I can inject fields with the `@Inject` annotation inside a fragment but i can't do it outside an android component class.

Comment: did you get anything?

Comment: No, i could not do it because Dagger does not allow to do what i was trying to do, so i pass the objects via constructor parameter, instead of the Inject annotation.

Comment: You need to annotate your ViewModel class with @HiltViewModel